# Creating backup process with a pi, should I use push or pull?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, raspberry-pi, rsync

I have a raspberry pi 4 and would like to use it as a backup server at home. Now I am unsure how to do this, I have an encrypted disk that is connected to the pi and I want to do the backup incremental using SSH with rsync. But should I push the files from my laptop to the pi or should the pi pull the files from my laptop?

**1. Pull**

a) **+** the laptop does not have write access to the backup, that is more safe

b) **-** the pi and the encrypted but mounted disk is at home all the time, could someone use this with physic access to get access to the data?

c) **-** similar to 1.b, the pi would need full access to my laptop, it could happen that it damages something on my laptop, I would try to use ssh forced command so it can only read and not write

**2. Push**

a) **+** only my laptop would be in full control, keys for the disk and the ssh connection is only on my laptop

b) **-** I could damage the backup, a ransomware or anything else could damage my backup. I am not sure if I could prevent this with a ssh forced command?!

Comment: That's a pretty good summary - I'm not sure if there's anything to add. Define your threat model and choose accordingly.

Comment: The system being backed up should never have write access to the backups themselves unless the only purpose to the backup is to allow restore from stupid user mistakes. to protect from many disaster-like events, the backups themselves should be minimally accessible. handle physical security with physical measures like locks, guards, etc. encryption of data at rest can help, but can also be compromised if the keys cann be extracted from the backup system.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few recommendations that I think must be addressed before deciding if you should push or pull the backup.

**0.a Ransomware Attack**

If the backup routine saves only the last version of your data and the ransomware transforms all unencrypted files into the encrypted version, upon syncing, it may delete all your files and replace with the encrypted ones, so the backup wouldn't be resilient if you suffer a ransomware. To solve this, you must have a minimum of 2 versions and pause syncing as fast as possible in the event of an attack or data loss/corruption so you can to preserve a good copy of your files.

**0.b Efficient Backup Storage**

I don't know exactly what FS you are using for the backup storage but (if not already) you might try using a solution which supports compression and deduplication like BTRFS or ZFS. This may help reduce the backup footprint and keeping 2 or more versions of your data occupying close to if you only had 1.

---

Assuming my suggestions are good and you want to follow or if you found a better idea to address the above observations, we can proceed to the main question.

**1. Pull**

> a) + the laptop does not have write access to the backup, that is more safe

Indeed, the less you expose the data or the mean to access it, the best. You reduce the attack possibilities by doing this.

> b) - the pi and the encrypted but mounted disk is at home all the time, could someone use this with physic access to get access to the data?

As long as the encrypted storage is password protected and any account with administrative rights also need a password, you might be safe. On each boot you would need to reinsert the password to mount the volume to ensure a reboot or external acess is not a mean to get to the data.

> c) - similar to 1.b, the pi would need full access to my laptop, it
> could happen that it damages something on my laptop, I would try to
> use ssh forced command so it can only read and not write

You can create an user specifically for the backup routine and add it to the required groups on both laptop and Pi. Such user would be added to the same groups as the main user on the laptop and permissions set would allow it to have a RO access to everything your user has. Note that among different devices there might be necessary to sync UIDs for this account so that the permissions remain consistent among devices.

---

**2. Push**

> a) + only my laptop would be in full control, keys for the disk and the ssh connection is only on my laptop

This would treat the Pi as a dumb but secure storage, like **1a**, the means to access the data are only at one end. You wouldn't need to create any user to do this since on the ssh you would login with the Pi user to make all the operations. Again, **1b** is relevant and recommended.

> b) - I could damage the backup, a ransomware or anything else could damage my backup. I am not sure if I could prevent this with a ssh forced command?!

If you follow recommendation **0.a** both issues can be circumvented assuming only the automated backup routine commands are run. If someone gets access to your laptop, make sure the keys for the Pi are not exposed without a password, so that if you must lose something, the other is still inaccessible.

---

According to the observations, I'd go with the **push**. It is less complicated to execute and it can be done on multiple devices if you want to. In the event of a data loss (corruption, ransomware, destruction) the backup routine will stop, ensuring that nothing other than a good copy is on the backup.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with much of what @joaopedro said but not his conclusions.

I'd go with Pull and use rsnapshot rather then rsync. Rsnapshot allows for incremental snapshots (using rsync and ssh) that allow you to easily keep track of versions in case someone modifies a file in unintended ways (think cryptolocker type attacks) and also makes recovery of a subset easier. (you can use file level tools like zfs, btrfs or lvs but rsync is lightweight, easy and filesystem agnostic. (rsnapshot uses symlinks and only duplicates changed files, while exposing multiple easy to view/copy trees of your data)

A pull is no harder to implement then a push if using ssh public keys.

Using pull rather then push and separate keys and limited access to the Pi can make Pull a lot more secure. Having the Pi connect from a low user level account (to the server as root or whatever lower access account you can safely get away with) and that is different from the default Pu login user account can further reduce exposure.

Be aware that you should ideally do multiple backups, rotated and off site to cover your bases.

Comment: just a sidenote because people are always referring to other tools than rsync to do incremental backups: rsync can do this pretty well itself with `--link-dest` using hardlinks. but of course rsnapshot and borgbackup can have other advantages in usage