# is physical acces to mounted encrypted disk a threat?

Tags: linux, encryption

Regarding my other question about backupping routines in [Creating backup process with a pi, should I use push or pull?](https://superuser.com/questions/1772610/creating-backup-process-with-a-pi-should-i-use-push-or-pull) I need to know more about decrypting encrypted disks etc.

So, if I have a pi (or any other computer) with a connected LUKS encrypted disk. I then SSH into the machine and decrypt and mount the disk. If now an attacker would get physical access to the pi and the disk, would they now be able to get access to the encrypted data somehow?

Or is just something that is theoretically more likely but could only be done with a high criminal effort and technical knowledge?

Comment: All bets are off if someone has physical access

Comment: It's really easy to acomplish this. The attacker creates an account with root access, waits for you to decrypt the encrypted FS, when you've done so, the attacker stops the SSH server, so you get kicked out, and now has full access to all decrypted files.

Comment: so disks aren't actually decrypted. that would take hours. blocks of data are decrypted/encrypted on the fly when you access them, and have the proper keys loaded into the program, but that also means that when the system is running and the disk is mounted, that the keys are in memory. That can allow them to be obtained by software, or even extracted from RAM using cold-boot and specialized hardware for storing raw memory. Full System encryption is a good way to protect a device that is physically accessible to the attacker, but only if the system is powered off or the disks unmounted.

Comment: basically even with full system encryption, for a well prepared adversary, physical access == root access. thats why physical security needs to be handled in the physical world, not the digital.

Comment: why is physical access == root access? If there is running but locked system how do you create a user with root access etc. ?

Comment: start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack . once you have the keys, nothing on the system will keep you out. then you just use the bootloader to load single-user mode, and reset the root password. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Guide/Reset_a_forgotten_root_password . this kind of attack requires some sophistication and often some hardware, but law enforcement, criminal attackers, etc (as you defined your threat actors) would be able to pull it off.